# Text Editor php MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, text, editor

I'm making a website and people can write blogs there, but I simply dont know where to start and how to search for something that might help me getting started with this.

What I would need is something like a text editor in html from from where I can then put the values into my database. The thing is I know how to make a text field and .... but the users must be able to add pictures and and diffrent text styles AND it still has to be safe to use so that they can not enter any code.

What can I search for on the internet to do this?

All ideas are welcome.

Comment: there are lots of open source text editors, you can use any one of them. why waste your time making a text editor. concentrate on your website logic rather than on the text editor.

Comment: @nura you have a good point there :p thx

Comment: Look into some open source content management systems (Drupal, Joomla, etc.)

Comment: [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/) or [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Comment: Here's a [whole bunch of JS editors](https://duckduckgo.com/c/JavaScript-based_HTML_editors). Try a few, I think CKEditor is very popular. Whilst this is an interesting question, bear in mind that very broad requests for assistance are discouraged here - sometimes it is necessary just to get a book and do some self-directed study.

Comment: Also look at [link]http://www.codecademy.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use jHtmlArea: http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com. It is easy to use and well documented.